# brew: unable to install mumps on mac

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to install ipopt by:

> brew install ipopt.rb --with-openblas

and I got the following error:

> ==> Installing dependencies for ipopt: mumps
>
> ==> Installing ipopt dependency: mumps
>
> ==> Downloading http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/MUMPS_5.1.1.tar.gz
>
> Already downloaded: /Users/yufeiliu/Library/Caches/Homebrew/mumps-5.1.1.tar.gz
>
> ==> make alllib LIBEXT=.dylib AR= -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name -Wl,/usr/local/Cellar/mumps/5.1.
>
> Last 15 lines from /Users/yufeiliu/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mumps/01.make:
>
> clang -fPIC -I../include -O  -c symbfac.c -o symbfac.o
>
> clang -fPIC -I../include -O  -c interface.c -o interface.o
>
> clang -fPIC -I../include -O  -c sort.c -o sort.o
>
> clang -fPIC -I../include -O  -c minpriority.c -o minpriority.o
>
> dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name -Wl,/usr/local/Cellar/mumps/5.1.1_1/lib/libpord.dylib -undefined dynamic_lookup -o libpord.dylib graph.o gbipart.o gbisect.o ddcreate.o ddbisect.o nestdiss.o multisector.o gelim.o bucket.o tree.o symbfac.o interface.o sort.o minpriority.o
>
> make[2]: dynamiclib: No such file or directory
>
> make[2]: [libpord.dylib] Error 1 (ignored)
>
> echo libpord.dylib
>
> libpord.dylib

```
if [ "./PORD/lib/" != "" ] ; then \
      cp ./PORD/lib//libpord.dylib lib/libpord.dylib; \
    fi;
```

> cp: ./PORD/lib//libpord.dylib: No such file or directory
>
> make[1]: *** [lib/libpord.dylib] Error 1
>
> make: *** [c] Error 2
>
> If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
>   https://github.com/brewsci/homebrew-science/issues

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately installation of mumps package with brew is very problematic at this moment. You have two different ways to install mumps

**Method 1:**

1. `brew tap brewsci/science`
2. `brew install mumps`
3. if that didn't work, download `mumps.rb` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/udacity/CarND-MPC-Project/master/mumps.rb)
4. `brew install ./mumps.rb`

**Method 2**

1. `brew tap dpo/openblas`
2. `brew install mumps`

The second method might lead to some issues with scalapack later.

**Update:** Unfortunately the above method might not work properly anymore.  I have updated the installation method [here](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/no-available-formula-with-the-name-mumps/1580/3?u=foadsf).